# Is Faraday's Law a conditional statement?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

Faraday's Law is of course:

$$\mathcal{E} = -\frac{d\Phi}{dt}$$

My contention is that the law should be written this way:

$$-\frac{d\Phi}{dt} \Rightarrow \mathcal{E}$$

In other words Faraday's law should be a conditional if then statement.

The reason is simple (I think?).
A misguided physics student might assert a constant Emf produces a changing magnetic flux.
Of course, this is physically incorrect.  However, it seems perfectly fine based on Faraday's law as it is usually stated.

For example:  Suppose $\mathcal{E}=10 $ V.
Misguided student plugs in $10$ V to the left side of Faraday's law.
Mathematically, at least, this implies a changing magnetic flux of $10 $ Tm$^2$/s.
I know this is incorrect in terms of Physics.  But what is the mathematical flaw, if there is one?

Comment: It is understood by everyone that the emf in that equation is the only the contribution  from a changing flux, not the total emf from every source. You can name it $\mathcal{E}_{\Phi}$, if that helps

Comment: The student _can_ be right, only (part of) the 10V could be from a battery or a capacitor that he somehow overlooked.

Comment: To my2cts assume the internal resistance of the battery is 0. 
To Pato I agree with you totally.  However, I don’t think I’ve ever seen a subscript or , better yet, a description to differentiate between induced emf and emf produced by a source of some sort.

Comment: Also , I don’t think it’s understood by everyone that the emf is the induced emf.  It’s something that no one seems to pay attention to.  Like gravitational mass versus inertial mass.   Both are casually called m but only because they happen to be equivalent.

Comment: @Ryan You are definitely wrong

Comment: If you write it as $$\oint\vec E\cdot\vec{\mathrm d\ell}=-\frac{\mathrm d\Phi}{\mathrm dt}$$, it becomes obvious that a constant EMF going around in a loop can only be coming from time rate of change of magnetic flux. Like, challenge the student to come up with a constant E field going in a loop using just batteries and resistors. There is no need for it to be written as a conditional; the logic can flow the other way.

Comment: @PatoGalmarini definitely wrong about what?  
To naturally inconsistent I’m focusing on the simple version of Faraday’s law.  That statement should be written as a conditional statement or should include a subscript.  That’s all I’m saying.

Comment: I misread your comment above mine.

Answer (score 1):

Faraday's law (sometimes called the flux rule to distinguish it from the closely related Maxwell-Faraday equation) can be written more precisely as
$$\mathcal E_{em} \equiv \oint\limits_C(\vec E+\vec v\times\vec B)\cdot d\vec \ell=-\frac{d\Phi}{dt}.$$
Here, $C$ is the loop along which we are calculating emf, $\Phi$ is the flux through it, and $\vec v$ is the velocity of the loop element $d \ell$. In this sense, the equation can be read both ways: if the integral is non-zero, there must be a time-varying flux.

Note however that $\mathcal E_{em}$, which we may call the *electromagnetic* or *induced emf*, doesn't include other possible sources of emf of a different origin, such as thermal or chemical. For example, a battery can provide a non-zero emf and cause current to flow around a stationary loop of wire, but $\mathcal E_{em}$ and $d\Phi/dt$ will still be zero if there is no time-varying external magnetic field.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  A subscript would take care of the issue.  I brought this up with a colleague and they looked at me like I was an idiot.